# Is there Susa art with two mountains and two suns? Or two mountains surrounded by the primordial ocean?

Tags: art, prehistory, persia

I've read [that](https://press.uchicago.edu/books/HOC/HOC_V1/HOC_VOLUME1_chapter4.pdf)

> [image]
>
> The bowl dates from the Amratian period, mid-fourth millennium B.C.
>
> Giedion sees this as portraying in abstract form the
> course of the sun from east to west, the enclosing primeval ocean, and the two central mountains of East and
> West, and indeed there is widespread acceptance of such
> an idea in the interpretation of decorated pottery from
> the Middle East and sites such as Susa.

But I've done a bit of searching online and I can't find any [Susa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susa) pottery or art that has that pattern (two triangle mountains and two suns). Surely there is Susa art with triangles probably depicting mountains, but these seem to be in longer chains e.g. [three](https://www.britishmuseum.org/collection/object/W_1924-0902-3) or [four](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/323792) (and no suns on those.)

So, is that claim correct? Is there such Susa art, with two mountains and two suns? Or at least two mountains surrounded by (something that can be interpreted as) the primordial ocean?

---

If it helps, there's also a footnote

> For
> interpretations of pottery from Susa, see Robert Klein, *Form and Meaning: Essays on the Renaissance and Modern Art*, trans. Madeline Jay and Leon Wiesel tier (New York: Viking Press, 1970), 146.

That book has a very short passage on Susa:

> The geometrical decorations of Susa ceramics in the 4th millenium B.C. suggest a cosmological scheme--with the earth in the center, the ocean around it, clouds and rain; [...]

followed by some discussion whether it's just us who attribute it this figurative meaning.

So there might not be two mountains but some other representation of the earth, and no two suns, but at least something that can interpreted as the primordial ocean. Still I'm not sure which Susa pottery fits that bill (the latter book has no plates/images.)

Comment: Not sure how/if it relates at all, since its talking about Egypt, but the answers to [this recent question on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/does-a-7000-year-old-ostrich-eggshell-held-at-the-nubian-museum-depict-a-drawing) show pottery with quite a few very similar-looking "mountains".

Comment: In fact, one answer shows what looks like a drawing of that exact platter, sourced to [this website](http://www.janine-elsaghir.de/ex2010-11/On%20the%20origins%20of%20the%20Egyptian%20Pantheon.htm), which calls it: "Solar symbolism on a White Cross Line platter (from D. Huyge: op. cit. p. 202 who has cited the image from W. Westendorf: Altägyptische Darstellungen des Sonnenlaufes auf der abschüssigen Himmelsbahn. Münchener Ägyptologische Studien 10. Berlin 1966, fig 27) Photographed from a black & white photocopy.". It also has that same platter picture later in the answer. Worth a read?